# ValueForKeyPath() returning something unexpected

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I am parsing this json:

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "Göteborg, Sverige" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "Stockholm, Sverige" ],
"rows" : [
   {
      "elements" : [
         {
            "distance" : {
               "text" : "467 km",
               "value" : 466568
            },
            "duration" : {
               "text" : "4 timmar 34 min",
               "value" : 16468
            },
            "status" : "OK"
         }
      ]
   }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Into an `NSDictionary` like this:

```
let dataDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

let distance = dataDict.valueForKeyPath("rows.elements.distance.value")
```

Now, this works, no crashes or errors. But, I expect it to return `466568` but instead it returns this:

```
(
        (
        466568
    )
)
```

I dont know why and I cant use it and cant cast it into anything :(

There is another question similar to this, but the answer there didnt help me because Im not the one to change the json, Google is. So please no hate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`valueForKeyPath` is returning a nested `NSArray`. You might want to cast it twice:

```
let distanceValue = ((distance as NSArray).objectAtIndex(0) as NSArray).objectAtIndex(0) as NSNumber
// or
let distanceValue = (distance as [NSArray])[0][0] as NSNumber
```

The `distance` value can't be directly accessed because `valueForKeyPath` does't implement a selector for array items.

Without `valueForKeyPath`:

```
let rows = dataDict.objectForKey("rows") as [NSDictionary]
let elements = rows[0]["elements"] as [NSDictionary]
let distance = elements[0]["distance"] as NSDictionary
let value = distance["value"] as NSNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because rows is giving you array instead of Dictionary. So first get the value of rows which will give you an array. Get the object at zero index of your array and assign it to Dictionary and then try to get elements.distance.value